# What is the name of this topic?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have seen some coding of condition checking inside the Numpy array,
like if the array is a = np.zeros((10,10))

and doing something like,

a[ a == 255 ] = 0

Now with this simple thing, I have seen people are doing complex things,
What is this concept called?

Comment: Boolean indexing [from the docs](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/arrays.indexing.html#boolean-array-indexing)

Comment: I suggest you to take a look at: https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/arrays.indexing.html

Comment: I think what you're after is "Vectorized Computation" https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/python-for-data/9781449323592/ch04.html (and in this case vectorized boolean checking)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it has a name beyond indexing. Each type can define what such indexing means though, so the common example of a list being an integer-indexed container is not the only thing you can do.

A `numpy.array` first overloads its `__eq__` operator so that an expression like `a == 255` doesn't return a single Boolean value. Instead, it returns an entire *array* of Boolean values, were the `i`th element of the result is True if `a[i] == 255`. That is, `result = a == 255` is similar to

```
result = [a[i] == 255 for i in range(len(a))]
```

Then, `__getitem__` is overloaded to handle the case where you try to index an array with *another* array. In this case, the result "selects" each element of the array where the corresponding Boolean value is true. The assignment

```
a[a == 255] = 0
```

then is roughly equivalent to

```
for x in range(len(a)):
    if (a == 255)[x]:
        a[x] = 0
```